# Dj-stripe 0.8.0 'djstripe_sync_customers' not working

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I know this is a vague question. But I am running Django 1.9.8, python 3.5 and djstripe 0.8.0 and the sync customers command doesn't work. When we run the

```
$python manage.py djstripe_sync_customers
```

command and return to the admin page the customers subscription status doesn't change. Meaning we have a customer who's card has expired and their subscription still shows active. another customer who has already made 2 monthly payments still shows as trial. However, if that user views their payment history via:

```
www.website.com/payments/history/
```

the Stripe info is synced correctly and all is good.

Has anyone run into this before? Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to some people about this issue and got an answer to my question. I was misunderstanding the purpose of

```
djstripe_sync_customers
```

All of what I was trying to accomplish is done through webhooks and this function doesn't do what I thought it did. Its too bad the dj-stripe docs are so bad!